macOS: Installing pkg file on Apple Silicon
Our app installer is a pkg-file. When running the installation on an M chip, macOS prompts the user to install Rosetta. Our app should be universal but is it correct that we get the Rosetta prompt because Apple's Installer.app is x86 (Intel)?


The Installer.app has a copyright from 2017 so perhaps it has not been updated since.
Is there a newer version of Installer.app?

I recently created a Universal macOS app that was distributed as a .pkg and did not receive prompts to install Rosetta.  I don't know what Installer.app is but I used pkgbuild to create the .pkg.

When you say "our app", is that an app you developed, or just some 3rd-party app? In the former case, you need to create a universal installer. And in the latter case... well, you need Rosetta.

I believe Installer.app is the app that runs the .pkg installation - anyway it launces when I double click the .pkg file. I've updated the original description with screen shots.

Yes, this is an app we have developed.
Btw., when Rosetta is first installed, you newer get the prompt again. And apparently, it's not possible to uninstall Rosetta (for test purposes).
